# Where is the implementation of the Appium Locator Strategies?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Using Appium to find UI-Elements within a WPF Application, I am searching for the place where the logic of the standard Appium/Selenium [Locator Strategies](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/index.html#selector-strategies), such as **ID**, **ClassName** or **XPath** are implemented.

What I need to do is to implement my own custom locator, but **without using xpath** at any place (*because xpath is not working for me, see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56597995/appium-unable-to-find-ui-elements-using-xpath)*)

*My idea is that if I understand how Appium/Selenium searches for an element whose node name is e.g. "ClassName", I can use this knowledge to implement a locator that looks for any custom node name such as "MyVeryCustomUINode".*

Is it that easy or am I mistaken?